# Draw pie Chart from a data frame

Tags: r

I have data frame with two variables; attendance 4 5 6 7 2 5 7 8 and another with treatment  A B B A A B B A. How do you make a pie chart comparing sum percentages of A and B in rstudio

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and the `pie` function, we first group by `treatment` and do the total sum per group.

```
a = data.frame(attendance=c(4,5,6,7,2,5,7,8),
                             treatment=c("A","B","B","A","A","B","B","A"),
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

A = a%>%group_by(treatment)%>%summarise(tot=sum(attendance))

pie(A$tot/sum(A$tot),labels=paste(A$treatment,round(A$tot/sum(A$tot),2)),main="Pie")
```

[image]